# Is there an inexpensive remote for the Nikon D300s?

Tags: nikon, wireless, nikon-d300

The Nikon D50 had a very inexpensive, but reliable wireless remote. Recently bought a D300s but don't want to purchase the expensive Nikon brand remote. Does anyone have a recommendation for an inexpensive but reliable alternative?

Comment: I am actually considering going for the D90 over the D300s because of this. I am not paying nearly $200 to replace my wonderful little $20 IR remote from my D70s!

Comment: Is it important to you that the remote be wireless?

Comment: I would prefer it to be wireless. That would allow me to be in the picture if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found infrared remotes to be too slow for my taste, and bought a cheap YongNuo RF-602 sender/receiver pair (less than $50) for my nikon.
It is not perfect, but way better than any infrared remote I ever owned: no need to point the remote to the cam, the delay is shorter, works over bigger distance.
I even bought extra cables so I can use it with any of my DSLR.

Oh, and it can be used to remote trigger your flash, too.

Answer (score 2):

maybe more than you need, but this is a very good wireless remote, about £80 or $100:-

http://www.hahnel.ie/index.cfm?page=dslrremotecontrols&id=60&pId=60

good for time lapse and bulb-mode, very flexible

Answer (score 2):

I bought a [Phottix Cleon II Wireless Remote N8](http://www.phottix.com/en/wireless-remotes/phottixr-cleon-ii.html) for £30 on eBay, from Hong Kong Supplies about 6 months ago. I see they're listing them for about $50 right now, and another seller has them for $35.

When I was looking I found that the [reviews](http://martybugs.net/blog/blog.cgi/gear/PhottixCleonIIWirelessRemote.html) were positive and it has been a brilliant little unit. Much, much better than the little infra-red unit I used with my D80 - it has far more options, an unsurprisingly better range and no longer do I have to point it at the camera to take the picture (handy when you're in the picture).

Answer (score 1):

I went through situation when I upgraded from my D50 to the D300s.  There isn't a cheap wireless remote.  You can get a cable release (MC30) for about $50.

Answer (score 0):

For the people in Europe there is a very good site which sells generic remotes (amongst other accessories).

The Nikon remote is in this [french site](http://www.jama.fr/boutique/fr/prise-de-vue/telecommande/telecommande-radio/telecommande-sans-fil-mq-nw2-nikon-1521).